# Power BI: Multiply Grouping by Related Parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm fairly new to Power BI, so may be overlooking something basic here.

I have a Column which contains a banding number (1 to 3), depending on a customer's total spend.

Band 1: 0 - 500
Band 2: 501 - 1000
Band 3: 1001+

I have created 3 Parameters on my report (Parameter 1, 2 and 3).
Each parameter allows for a decimal range between 5 and 35 with increments of 2.5
This parameter will represent the percentage of the income that is earned by a consultant.

I'm trying to create a measure that multiplies the Income by the respective Parameter. Allowing users to adjust the percentage earning dynamically when viewing the report.

Below is an example of the table.
Table Name: Receipts

| Policy Number | Client Name | Band | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SA1 | Ray Mann | 3 | 800 |
| SA2 | Ray Mann | 3 | 900 |
| SA3 | Mary Yu | 2 | 600 |
| SA4 | Sam Fry | 1 | 20 |
| SA5 | Sam Fry | 1 | 50 |

I'm a little lost on this one.
As a calculated columns I would do a simple SWITCH statement, however as it's not a measure it will not adjust dynamically as the parameter slider is changed.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Morallis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say there are three what-if parameters, named `Parameter1`, `Parameter2` and `Parameter3`, and your table is named `Table`. We can create a measure, which first will use [SUMMARIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax) to summarize the data calculating the total income per band:

```
SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Band], "Income", SUM('Table'[Income]))
```

Then will use [SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) to calculate the multiplied income:

```
Multiplied Income = 
    SUMX(
        SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Band], "Income", SUM('Table'[Income])),
        [Income] * SWITCH([Band],
            1, Parameter1[Parameter1 Value], 
            2, Parameter2[Parameter2 Value], 
            3, Parameter3[Parameter3 Value],
            1)
        )
```

The result will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrey! This worked like a charm and it's so simple and I can take this and apply it to some other projects I'm playing with.